# what other ways are there to submit a form to a (MVC) controller?

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

So straightforward HTML offers a form that can be "submitted" to a designated (MVC) controller, and the $_POST contains all the data from the form.

What other ways are there to take all the form data and send it to a controller? I've been trying rather unsuccessfully with ajax, and I'm sure it can be done, ... but are there any other ways to do it?

**UPDATE:**
I think one of the fundamental things that I'm struggling with is that a lot of the advice seems to expect that I'm struggling with my server side response to my ajax call. I'm not. I actually don't care about a server side response. I'm trying to pick up the form data to send down a dead end to a pdf. I can't use HTML because that is already setup to do the form validation and posting to database.

Comment: Do you want the AJAX way of the code?

Comment: Well, that would be amazing, but I've been busy for most of the day so far without success, so I'm not that optimistic :(

Comment: Or asking for alternative way other than `simply form post` and `AJAX`?

Comment: The problem is I need to post the form data twice. I can do it once via straight HTML to the PDF creator script, OR the database writing script, but not both. So I need another method (like ajax)

Comment: To avoid sending the same data twice perhaps you can pass the information to the pdf creator script after writing it into the database?

Answer (score 1):

Try below code,

**Controller:**

```
class Controller_name extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function function_name()
    {
        if($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST')
        {
            $data = $this->input->post();

            // below code will print an array consisting your form data
            echo "<pre>"; print_r($data);

            // now, do whatever database/other action with this data

            // below is the response back
            // uncomment below code if want response also

            // header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
            // $json = array();
            // if(all went well)
            // {
            //    $json["success"] = true;
            // }
            // else
            // {
            //    $json["success"] = false;
            // }
        }
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
<form action="/other_controller/other_function/" ajax-action="/controller_name/function_name/" method="POST" name="my_form"> 
    <input name="name" type="text" />
    <input name="email" type="text" />

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $("form[name='my_form']").on("submit", function(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this);
        var data = form.serialize();
        var action = form.attr("ajax-action");

        $.post(action, data)

        // below is the response back
        // uncomment below code if want response also

        // .done(function(response){
        //    if(response.success == true)
        //    {
                // if form posted successfully, do something
        //    }
        //    else
        //    {
               // if form failed, do something else
        //    }
        // });
    });
});
</script>
```

**Explanation:**

1) In view, we've created a form having 2 actions. Normal action for your PDF creation and the other `user defined action` named as attribute **`ajax-action`** for database/other work.
2) Since, we are using `jquery` for `AJAX`, we've added its library.
3) We've picked up the event **`on submit`** of the form named `my_form`.
4) **`ev.preventDefault()`** prevents the `default action` of a `particular event` (here it is on submit).
5) **`$(this)`** will be our form as a `object` which we are storing it in a variable.
6) **`form.serialize()`** will `serialize` the form data which we'll be using for POST request.
7) **`$.post(url, data)`** will generate a POST request to the mentioned `url` with mentioned `data`.
8) **`.done(function(){})`** will capture the `response` after the request is completed.
9) Over the Controller side, we're getting the POST data and doing some database/other actions.
10) After the above actions completes and if it all happened successfully, we'll send back a **`json`** data back to our view.
11) **`header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8')`**.The Content-type header is just used as info for your application. The browser doesn't care what it is. The browser just returns you the data from the AJAX call. **`application/json`** will parse the response data as **`json`**.

**Usage of above code:**

1) If you just want a simple form submit with no response, let the uncommented code as it it.
2) If want some response use the uncommented code as suited.

Comment: Kindly use the updated code as I did some typo before.

Comment: OK, some progress ... I'm getting the PDF created, by means of ajax I presume. But I am not seeing the second form action. What I did was uncomment your code (controller), and add in an `alert ("success")` - which never appears. Also, there is no function "is_post()" that I can find.

Comment: Actually yes. `is_post()` is not a pre-defined function in `input class`. Its way done by extending core input class. Hence it have edited that part and made it simple. There might be some issue in response code. Check your browser console for debugging.

Comment: Are you aware that the fPDF code is designed to terminate all scripts on the generation of the PDf document. Don't know why, but it's a known feature or issue. So maybe I have to also try re-order the sequence - database/other work first, then pdf.

Answer (score 0):

To use AJAX in CI is exactly the same as any other PHP - AJAX request.

As CI is just a framework you can simply just use PHP `$_POST[];` like you would in any other application.

However, there are a couple of built-in functions which are handy

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html

```
$this->input->post('post_value');
```

Used as follows:-

```
private $postedItem;

public function getAJAX(){

      $this->postedItem = $this->input->post('post_value');

     if($this->postedItem){
          //do something with the post - now accessible through $this->postedItem.
     }

}
```

Then just post your data to

```
controller/getAJAX
```

As with any AJAX post to PHP - just serialise your form data, send it to a URL (controller/method); deserialise and process.

If you are struggling with this I would suggest you need to build the part you are struggling with outside of CI as plain PHP get it working and then port into your CI application - I suspect your problem is not CI related.

Comment: My problem is the "... the same as any other PHP - AJAX request..." I'm just not getting ajax.